# Delaying execution of AJAX downloaded script for the purposes of returning the value to the function that called it

Tags: jquery

I am not sure exactly how to ask this question, but here goes. Please note this is overly stipped code based on my scenario.

As detailed below, I have a JavaScript function on the client that calls the server to retrieve data, which maybe either HTML or JS. I want to reuse the called function with many scenarios so I do not want to hard code the content type returned by the server. The problem I am having is when the AJAX returns, it has already evaluated the JS and I am not sure how to get the results from the JS to append to DOM where I want it to go.

I am sure I don't have to explain but the chain of events are:

1. User clicks button
2. Click routed to function dummy
3. Function dummy loads the data via AJAX from Server, which may be
   HTML or JS

I want to have the result from the AJAX call routed back to the function dummy so that it can then append the data to the div with an id of "canvas". I do not want to use eval, and I am confused about the call and apply methods which look as if they maybe useful, but I have no idea. I do not want to create the content on the server and send it. I want the client to handle the UI elements.

What should I do to resolve this or is there a better way of doing what I need this to do?

Thanks

Client-Side JS/JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".getcanvas").click(function(e){
            dummy("/someurl");
        });
    }
    function fetch(obj) {
        var defaults, settings, oD, oS, oX;
        if (!(obj.url === undefined)) {
            defaults = {type:"GET",timeout:4000,async:false,success:function(iD,iS,iX){oD=iD;oS=iS;oX=iX;}};
            settings = $.extend({}, defaults, obj); 
            $.ajax(settings);          
        } 
        return {"data":oD, "status":oS, "state":oX};        
    }
    function get(url) {
        var s = fetch({url: url});
        return s.data;
    }
    function dummy(url) {
        $("div#canvas").append(get(url));
    }
    function dothis(json) {
        var res = '';
        json = $.parseJSON(json);

        $.each(json.objects, function(index, object) {
            res += '<div id="+object.id+">'+object.message+'</div>';
        }
        return res;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Something</title></head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas"/>
        <input type="button" class="getcanvas" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

SERVER @ /someurl:

```
    <script>
    var o = '{objects:[{id:57,message:"testing"},{id:45,"somethingnew"}]}';
    dothis(o);
    </script>
```

Comment: Can't you use a callback? Otherwise, that kinda defeats the point of *Asynchronous* JavaScript And XML.

Comment: Synchronous XHR is a bad idea.

Comment: `async:false` is deprecated( see docs) and there is rarely a valid use case to use it. Can use success callback or `$.deffered` to handle your needs

Comment: @minitech I am using a callback to return the data to the caller. To the other two, that still doesn't answer the question of how to get the data produced by the called function to be returned to the original caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just return the code from server without `<script>` tags and then later append it with script tags.

**EDIT**

You can append it like this:

```
$("div#canvas").append("<script>" + get(url) + "</script>");
```

Comment: I like the train of thought so I will accept this, but I need the dummy function to accept either HTML or a script.

Comment: I don't know why you want it to be HTML but if it makes sense for your project you can wrap the script into a `div` tag instead of a `script` tag and then re-wrap it in the `script` tag on client side.